# Trouble with prepositions

Tags: prepositions, word-order

I want to write the sentence "start date of the period being aggregated over"

However, I know one is not supposed to end a sentence in a preposition.  I can't think of a good alternative to this sentence that doesn't sound incredibly awkward.

I thought of something like "Start date over which the period is being aggregated?" But it isn't the "period" that is being aggregated; it is the "data" in the period that is being aggregated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with ending a sentence with a preposition. Just leave it as you've written it, or you'll end up with something totally unnatural. Btw, what you've written is not a completer sentence, but just a fragment.

Comment: Your thought might be improved as "Start date of the period over which the data is being aggregated"; but why not omit *over* altogether in your first version? "Start date of the period being aggregated" -- that's perfectly understandable.

Comment: @BillJ I find "start date of the period being aggregated over" awkward and somewhat difficult to parse.  I agree that there's nothing intrinsically wrong with ending a sentence with a preposition.  Automatic avoidance of it is problematic at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Start date for period of aggregation".